# Set headerBackVisible to false on some screens

Tags: react-native, expo

I have _layout through expo-router Stack and i want to disable back button on some screens.
When I log out, a back button appears on the login screen, which takes me back to the app's home page. I want to hide this button from the header.

This is my code

```
export default function Layout() {
    return (
        <Stack
            screenOptions={{
                headerTitle: () => (
                    <Image
                        source={logo}
                        style={{ width: 30, height: 30, borderRadius: 5 }}
                    />
                ),
                headerBackVisible:
                    useNavigation().getState().routes[0].name === "login" ||
                    useNavigation().getState().routes[0].name === "register"
                        ? false
                        : true,
                headerTitleAlign: "center",
                headerBackTitleVisible: false,
                headerShadowVisible: true,
                headerStyle: { backgroundColor: "#ebf3ff" },
                headerRight: () =>
                    useNavigation().getState().routes[0].name === "login" ||
                    useNavigation().getState().routes[0].name === "register" ? null : (
                        <Button
                            onPress={() => {
                                router.push("/settings");
                            }}
                            color="transparent"
                        >
                            <Icon name="settings" type="feather" size={24} color="#435ebe" />
                        </Button>
                    ),
            }}
        />
    );
}
```

My index.js

```
return Platform.OS === "web" ? (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
            <Text style={Styles.heading}>{i18n.t("expoNotSupportedAlert")}</Text>
        </View>
    ) : (
        <StackNav.Navigator>
            {value === null ? (
                <>
                    <StackNav.Screen
                        options={{ headerShown: false }}
                        name="Login"
                        component={LoginScreen}
                    />
                    <StackNav.Screen
                        options={{ headerShown: false }}
                        name="Register"
                        component={RegisterScreen}
                    />
                </>
            ) : (
                <>
                    <StackNav.Screen
                        options={{ headerShown: false }}
                        name="Home"
                        component={HomeScreen}
                    />
                    <StackNav.Screen
                        options={{ headerShown: false }}
                        name="Add Meters"
                        component={AddMeters}
                    />
                    <StackNav.Screen
                        options={{ headerShown: false }}
                        name="Add Readings"
                        component={AddReadings}
                    />
                    <StackNav.Screen
                        options={{ headerShown: false }}
                        name="Readings"
                        component={ReadingScreen}
                    />
                    <StackNav.Screen
                        options={{ headerShown: false }}
                        name="Settings"
                        component={SettingsScreen}
                    />
                    <StackNav.Screen
                        options={{ headerShown: false }}
                        name="Archive"
                        component={ArchiveScreen}
                    />
                </>
            )}
        </StackNav.Navigator>
    );
```

I tried the if function but it doesn't work.

```
headerBackVisible:
  useNavigation().getState().routes[0].name === "login" ||
  useNavigation().getState().routes[0].name === "register"
    ? false
    : true,
```